# Excel VBA row copy into archive

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a whole bunch of rows into an archive with VBA. (VBA noob here). I have two sheets, 1 called Active, and the Archive. In active I have a column called Job Number which is what the other data is based off of. I need to copy all the rows where job numbers is not blank and copy each row individually over to my archive sheet where a empty row is available. and then clear the job number cell.

At the bottom is what i have so far. Basically i need to take all rows that have have an nonempty cell in column e.( i tried to count rows until last non empty records --> NumRows) also find the location of the last non empty variable in Archive (lr2) and then i tried a for loop to copy over but it doesn't do anything.    Any help would be awesome.

```
Sub Archiver()
Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long, NumRows As Integer
lr2 = Sheets("Archive").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
For r = 5 To NumRows
    Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Archive").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
    lr2 = Sheets("Archive").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then edit your question to create a [clear, definable programming problem]([how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry. I should have made it clearer. I have no VBA experience. If you know somewhere I can learn to do something like this (directed not just a general learn VBA) that would helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Archiver()
Dim lr2 As Long
Dim y As Worksheet, z As Worksheet
Dim copyRng As Range


Set y = Sheets("Active")
Set z = Sheets("Archive")

lr2 = y.Cells(rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

'Here you select the range of your sheet you want to copy, for me is A:E
Set copyRng = y.Range("A2:E" & lr2)

z.Range("A2:E" & copyRng.rows.Count + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
copyRng.Copy z.Range("A2")

y.Range("A2:E" & lr2).ClearContents

End Sub
```